# Webmin - Raw reads and raw writes?

Tags: network-share, file-sharing, webmin

First of all, apologies if this is posted in the wrong category.

I use Webmin 1.780 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and under the `Windows File Sharing`, under `Miscellaneous Options` there are 2 options:

- `Allow raw reads?`
- `Allow raw writes?`

Does anyone know what each of these functions do? I have tried Webmin's documentations but I haven't been able to find it.

Notice the two options at the centre of the web page.

[image: Notice the two options at the centre of the web page.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here from SAMBA doc: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html#id2690809

> Read Raw
>
> The read raw operation is designed to be an optimized, low-latency
>   file read operation. A server may choose to not support it, however,
>   and Samba makes support for read raw optional, with it being enabled
>   by default.
>
> In some cases clients do not handle read raw very well and actually
>   get lower performance using it than they get using the conventional
>   read operations, so you might like to try read raw = no and see what
>   happens on your network. It might lower, raise, or not affect your
>   performance. Only testing can really tell.
>
> Write Raw
>
> The write raw operation is designed to be an optimized, low-latency
>   file write operation. A server may choose to not support it, however,
>   and Samba makes support for write raw optional, with it being enabled
>   by default.
>
> Some machines may find write raw slower than normal write, in which
>   case you may wish to change this option.

And from Oreilly:http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/appb_02.html

> B.2.2.3 read raw and write raw
>
> These are important performance configuration options; they enable
>   Samba to use large reads and writes to the network, of up to 64KB in a
>   single SMB request. They also require the largest SMB packet
>   structures, SMBreadraw and SMBwriteraw, from which the options take
>   their names. Note that this is not the same as a Unix raw read. This
>   Unix term usually refers to reading disks without using the files
>   system, quite a different sense from the one described here for Samba.
>
> In the past, some client programs failed if you tried to use read raw.
>   As far as we know, no client suffers from this problem any more. Read
>   and write raw default to yes, and should be left on unless you find
>   you have one of the buggy clients.